# Conectar node js con firebird

Tags: nodejs, asp, firebird

Hola a todos de nuevo...

Tengo una bd FirBird 2.1 que está siendo usada por una aplicación cliente y he hecho otras cosas mas con php para publicr en web.

La cuestión es que deseo construir una ASP y quiero probar con node.js del lado del servidor.

Alguno de ustedes tendrá o habrá efectuado la conexión hacia Firebird usando node.js?

Gracias de antemano.

Slds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, es super fácil con ésta librería:

[Firebird Node](https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird)

Luego incluir la librería en el proyecto

```
var Firebird = require('node-firebird');
```

y va un ejemplo quitado de la misma fuente que te pasé

```js
Firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {

    if (err)
        throw err;
        db.query('SELECT * FROM TABLE', function(err, result) {
        db.detach();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Alexis,

Ya instalé el node-firebird, hice el mismo ejemplo que me diste donde attach debería ser para establecer la conexión?

Bueno, me arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un error de I/O pero no se que puede ser, me puedes echar una mano?

Ulises

Comment: si no me equivoco es porque estas tratando de crear el archivo database.fdb y ya lo tienes osea tienes que verificar si existe, y solo si no existe crearlo. sería mejor que cambies en tu pregunta e insertes tu codigo asi vemos si podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Probé cambiando el nombre de la base de datos pero salio el mismo error... puse el código fuente...

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto el código que está en archivo fb.js:

```
//
// conn firebird con node.js
//

// inyecciones
var http=require('http');
var url=require('url');
var fs=require('fs');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var firebird=require('node-firebird');

// opciones base de datos
var options = {};

options.host = '127.0.0.1';
options.port = 3050;
options.database = 'database.fdb';
options.user = 'SYSDBA';
options.password = 'masterkey';
options.lowercase_keys = false; // set to true to lowercase keys
options.role = null;            // default
options.pageSize = 4096;        // default when creating database

firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    // db = DATABASE
    db.query('SELECT * FROM EMPRES', function(err, result) {
        // IMPORTANT: close the connection
        db.detach();
    });

});
```

Comment: Probé cambiando nombre a la base de datos, es decir no existe... pero arroja el mismo error...

Answer (score 0):

ya me pude conectar... había que escribir toda la ruta en options.database.

Ahora ya puedo ver una tabla mediante console.log, veré una manera más elegante de mostrarla por html y publicaré mis avances...

Gracias